# Unable to write cache folder for smarty project on pagodabox

Tags: php, smarty3, server-configuration

I have created project in smarty and now i am trying to host it on [pagodabox.com](http://www.pagodabox.com). I have created application on pagodabox.com and uploaded all code on to this application but problem is this now i am unable to configure cache and compiler directory in pagodabox.com that's why it output fetal error because cache and compiler directory is read only mode. I have try Boxfile to resolve this issue but failing to solve. I am not aware how i can make these directory writable. please help me. this is url of project `http://moviestock.pagodabox.com/` and following is my Boxfile configuration

```
web1: #component type & number
  name: blog            #component settings
  shared_writable_dirs:
    - var/secured/cache
    - var/secured/compiler
    - var/sessions
  document_root: app
  php_version: 5.3.8
```

and i am getting this following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'unable to write file   
shared/secured/compiler/wrt50c17dfaca2932.90478039' in 
/var/www/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php:44 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(201): 
Smarty_Internal_Write_File::writeFile('shared/secured/...', 'compileTemplateSource() #2  
/var/www/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(374): 
Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('extends:layout....', '6666cd76f969564...', NULL, 
NULL, true) #3 /var/www/classes/BaseController.php(22): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase-
>display('extends:layout....', '6666cd76f969564...') #4 
/var/www/secured/controllers/HomeController.php(6): BaseController->render('home') #5 
[internal function]: HomeController->indexAction('') #6 
/var/www/classes/Router.php(26): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #7 
/var/www/index.php(10): Router::run() #8 in 
/var/www/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 44
```

Comment: have made sure that your script have write permission to these (sub ) folders? That could be the only problem.

Comment: yes i know that but how i can enable permisson for write in folder on pagodabox server

Comment: that I am sorry but I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the filepath that smarty is trying to write to. In the error, the filepath is `shared/secured/compiler/wrt50c17dfaca2932.90478039`. It should be `var/secured/compiler/wrt50c17dfaca2932.90478039`

Comment: Please see now its saying 

    Not Found
    
    The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe `@chmod(PATH,0770);` will make a trick?

Comment: well, I thought to use it in PHP file

Comment: no m sorry dear this is not working on pagodabox i think shared directory can be created by Boxfile but don't know what wrong i am doing